# Which affordable magnetometer to purchase?

Tags: cubesat, attitude-determination-and-control

I am involved in a CubeSat team that will fly a mission in low earth orbit. I will be working on ADCS so would like to gain experience with the magnetometer. I am just not sure which one to buy. Is there a reliable standard magnetometer that people use for low earth orbit? My understanding is that fluxgate are the norm but I see a large range of prices and not sure which to buy. If anyone has a specific one they like that is also affordable, I'm all ears.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of question is referred to as a "shopping list question" and generally regarded as off-topic for StackExchange sites because the answer rapidly goes out of date.  ...also, welcome to the world of aerospace, where your every purchase decision ends up leaving you with gnawing doubts! It's even more fun later on when/if it's government money.

Comment: *Welcome to Space SE!* As Erin Anne points out, "Which one should I buy?" questions are generally closed in all Stack Exchange sites unless modified. In addition to answers having low long-term value, it opens up the site to folks pushing specific products via fake Q&A. You could ask why there is such a large range of prices but really what I think you want to ask is "From such a wide range of prices and performance specifications for fluxgate magnetometers, how do I go about choosing one for my particular cubesat?" Be sure to explain your ADCS requirements (accuracy, response time etc.)